# JQuery replace src attribute substring

Tags: jquery, html, css, rollover

I'd like to replace the 2's with 1's for the image src in all matching classes. I've tried something similar for specific elements and thats works, but I can't get it to work for all matching classes. How do I change the format of the first call so it works? Thanks.

```
$(".in1, .in2, .in3").click(
    function()
    {    
        $(".in1, .in2, .in3").attr("src").replace("2","1");// This doesn't work

        if(this.src.indexOf("1")!=-1){
            this.src = this.src.replace("1","2"); // This works
        }else{
            this.src = this.src.replace("2","1"); // This works
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

`.attr("src")` is a getter and not a setter.

if you want it as a setter, you can do this,

```
.attr("src", function(i,src){
   return (src.indexOf("1")!=-1)?src.replace("1","2"):src.replace("2","1");
});
```

requires jQuery 1.4 + , [`.attr()` <sup>link</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr#attr2)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".in1, .in2, .in3").attr('href', function(index, attr) {
   return attr.replace('1', '2');
});
```